# Bootstrap modal images not working - Multiple

Tags: boo

I just followed w3school tutorial for this bootstrap modal image. I have two image cards in my page. So I need to popup that two images. But it's working with one image only.

[Link to w3school article](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp)

```
 <!-- Trigger the Modal -->

<img id="myImg" src="http://d14dsi4x2zx6ql.cloudfront.net/files/styles/welcome_image/public/VCW_TI_5_BayLoop_Hero_Manley_1280x642_sized.jpg?itok=EaARDZt8" alt="">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

I insert "myImg" id in my other image, but it didn't work. First image popup worked as I expect. What will be missing here?

Comment: You cannot use the same ID on more than one element on the page, as they are unique. However, you can use multiple classes, if that helps.

Comment: Why does this question has the `boo` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't give two elements the same id 
if you want to do the same action for both you can give them class

```
<img class="myImg" src="http://placehold.it/850x450" alt="image1" width="200">
<img class="myImg" src="http://placehold.it/700x400/f00" alt="image2" width="200">
```

and js will be:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
//iterate over img to add click event for each one,, jquery will make it much easier
for(var i=0;i< img.length;i++){
  img[i].onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
}

//jquery option
/*$('.myImg').on('click', function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = $(this).attr('src');
  captionText.innerHTML = $(this).attr('alt');
})*/

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/am2a6qpo/)

Comment: Omg! I just forgot the basic of HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Id must be unique, See an example here. https://fiddle.jshell.net/wg5p60g7/